# Why int b; has 16 value in shell/terminal?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b;

}
```

Why b has 16 value when i compile this? I cant understand why b has 16 not 0. Int doesnt have 0 as default value?

Comment: define variable in c++ without initialize in future it will give undefined value.

Comment: You have stumbled upon something super important, and not to forget in the future. When you declare a variable, its value is basically random. This is why you should always initialise a variable before using its value.

Comment: @N0ll_Boy the behavior is undefined, which is different from having undefined values. For example on some architectures like Itanium, accessing an uninitialized variable will give you a segfault

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not. C++ does not initialise variables unless you ask it to. (Setting a variable to 0 for example is at least one instruction: typically `reg XOR reg`. That could be wasteful.) The behaviour of reading an uninitialised `int` is undefined.

(Note you can do some things with uninitialised variables, such as setting a pointer or reference to one, computing `sizeof(a)`, and using `decltype(a)`. But passing it by value to a function is undefined behaviour. That often trips up even professional programmers.)

Comment: so i have to write all the time  for example: int a = 0;?

Comment: Again, absolutely not. Only if you need to read the value before you write something sensible to it.

Comment: I did this:
 int a;
    int b;
    
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b;

    a += 1;
    b += 2;
    
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b;

and i got 161 and 18 values.

Comment: @lolorek well you don't **have to**, but it is advisable to always initialize variabels. That doesn't mean you should initialize everything with `0`, but rather only declare a variable when you can initialize it with something meaningful. Not always this is possible, but thats the exceptions

Comment: `a += 1` is a read of an uninitialised `a`. You are  incrementing the value.

Comment: i did this
 int a;
    
    a + 10;
    cout<<a;

and i got 0

Comment: @lolorek: `a + 10` is an uninitialised read of `a`. Can you not see that? Did you mean `a = 10`?

Comment: The best thing to do is not declare `int a` until you have a value for it. `int a = 0;` can be problematic, e.g. if you want to divide by `a`.